# Is it good practice to execute a stored procedure by writing it as a string?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Is this following a good practice or not?

```
cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName_InsertUserDetails"; //Is this line a good or bad since Sql injection is possible here.
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name",SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value=name;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@age",SqlDbType.Int)).Value=age;
```

Comment: Without knowing the real context in which you are using this line of code, it is very hard to give a proper answer. However, As the command is a constant string, I don't see any problems with that code (again, looking coldly to these lines, without knowing the context).

Comment: Who gives you that string? Do you let your user choose the Stored Procedure to execute? Also to run a stored procedure you need to set the CommandType

Comment: Sql injection is not possible here. Only if you built the command text dynamically and it doesn't seems to be the case here.

Comment: That is not a sql injection vulnerability. I like to use static read only string fields for stored procedure names so that you can't type it wrong when used in multiple places you have no choice but to provide a string to `CommandText`.

Comment: SQL injection is not possible here - on the assumption that `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: @MartinSmith and making the assumption that the stored procedure is not using dynamic sql and munging a big string together. ;)

Comment: **Thanks**, I got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code with added `Commandtype`:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName_InsertUserDetails"; // This line is ok
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name",SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value=name;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@age",SqlDbType.Int)).Value=age;
```

> Is it good practice to execute a stored procedure by writing it as a
>   string?

**What could go wrong?**

- SQL Injection? When you set `CommandText` as hard-coded string as shown above, there is no possibility to SQL Injection attack.
- Stored procedure name not sync with calling code: You can get run-time exceptions if calling code refers to unknown stored proc.

  - Keep your stored procedure creation scripts under version control, near to your code which uses it. This way it is possible to keep stored procedure in sync with C# code.
  - Automatic tests can be created to notice if Stored Proc has breaking changes

If your Stored procedure inserts only single `UserDetails` entity, you can also make use of Entity Framework. [This article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/code-first-insert-update-delete-stored-procedure-mapping.aspx) shows  how to map entity CUD (*Create, Update, Delete*) operations to Stored Procedures automatically by calling  `MapToStoredProcedures()` in Fluent API. Article also explains how you can map your own custom Stored Procedures to your EF Entities.

Comment: *Unit testing can be created to notice if Stored Proc has breaking changes*. That would not be a unit test. Unit tests run in isolation with no external dependencies. What you're talking about would be an integration test.